# Methods for sending out activation emails within a web solution

Tags: asp.net, email

We have a web site that requires users to signup and they then receive an activation email

Our current method of doing this is including the whole email process within the registration thread itself i.e.

```
Register() {
   registerUser()
   sendActivationMail()
   return View(Successpage)
}
```

Where sendActivationMail then contains all the necessary code to connect to our mail server and send the email etc. We know this isn't the best way to do it, rather we just did this quickly to test everything out. The problem is obvious, the user ends up waiting longer for the "thank you for signing up page" as the page is only returned after everything else has finished.

The options to this properly that we're aware of are:

1. Start a new thread to send out the email once the database side of the registration is complete and return the original thread immediately.
2. Persist the email to the database and have a thread that runs contiounously and checks the database for new emails to send every x minutes
3. Use a third party email service such as Amazon Simple Email Service.

Are there any other methods to use? Do any of the above stand out as the best?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use a database to queue the messages and I have a service application that runs continuously and checks the queue and sends them out. We have a bunch of web applications that send emails so they all put into the queue. This works for us. I am sure there are pros and cons to it but like I said, It works for us.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your needs.

The advantage of method 2 that if the sending failed you can retry/decide on what to do.

Another method that is similar to the DB is some Queue infrastructure like MSMQ or other.